# Getting Haskell's hsenv to work on Ubuntu 13

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, sudo

I'm trying to get `GHC` working on Ubuntu. Did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ghc
sudo apt-get install cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install hsenv
```

Then I tried to create a `hsenv` environment and got the following:

```
xx@xx-VirtualBox:~/scm/t1$ hsenv
Creating Virtual Haskell directory structure
Installing GHC
Initializing GHC Package database at /home/xx/scm/t1/.hsenv/ghc_pkg_db
Copying necessary packages from original GHC package database
  Failed to copy optional package ghc-binary from system's GHC: 
    /usr/bin/ghc-pkg process failed with status 1
  Using user-wide (~/.cabal/packages) Hackage download cache directory
Installing cabal config at /home/xx/scm/t1/.hsenv/cabal/config
Installing activate script
Installing cabal wrapper using /home/xx/scm/t1/.hsenv/cabal/config at /home/xx/scm/t1/.hsenv/bin/cabal
Skipping 'cabal update' step, Hackage download cache already downloaded
  to ~/.cabal/packages/. You can update it manually with 'cabal update'
  (from inside or outside the virtual environment).
```

The key message being here:

> Failed to copy optional package ghc-binary from system's GHC:

How do I resolve this problem? It seems to be the only impediment at the moment.

Comment: I get this on the Mac, too, but it doesn't seem to stop me from using hsenv.

Comment: Ditto various other Linux distros.

Comment: Is ghc-binary supposed to be installed as part of the ghc package?

Comment: Runs just fine for me on ubuntu

Comment: I see the same message on Arch Linux and hsenv works fine -- I've been using it every day for months and had never even noticed this message.  Well spotted!

Answer (score 1):

It is a `hsenv`s bug arising from [this line](https://github.com/Paczesiowa/hsenv/blob/b904436e10bde707a7838661a5ec30de430ca2b9/src/Actions.hs#L289). It seems, in recent GHC versions this package was renamed to `binary`.

But `hsenv` is an obsolete projects anyways, it is recommended to use new `cabal-install` or `stack`.